Does the UV index over a day form a Gaussian?
If you go to a website such as this that shows a plot of the UV index throughout the day, you will see that the plot for each day resembles a Gaussian distribution. Perhaps someone with access to raw data can enlighten us to how good the fit is to a Gaussian (or maybe Lorentzian)? Is there any easy way to predict a formula for the curve?
